# How should I add the rows (without the headers) after the last row with data (without overwriting anything in the "Master_db")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below is overwriting on the existing data.

@OMila helped me with the original code, I could not articulate exactly what I needed hence starting a new question.

```
function Dom() {
  var origin_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Dom_Sum');
  var firstRow = 1;
  var firstCol = 1;
  var numRows = origin_sheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = 22;
  var origin_values = origin_sheet.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, numRows, numCols).getValues();
  var dest_values = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < origin_values.length; i++) {
    if(origin_values[i][0] != '') {
      dest_values.push(origin_values[i]);
    }
  }
  var dest_id = "1ZGq7L7bvF1INuDgZxhHnVsihkYkYubmncSAE5uC-Pq4";
  var dest_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dest_id).getSheetByName("Master_Db");
  var numRowsDest = dest_values.length;
  var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRowsDest, 22);
  dest_range.setValues(dest_values);


}
```

I would like to add the data created in the "Dom_Sum" worksheet below the last row of data in the other workbook with the worksheet name "Master_Db"
@OMila I'm really grateful to you, and if you like we could offer you a consultation fee for future projects. (boseav@gmail.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing your value into the range `dest_sheet.getRange(1, 1, numRowsDest, numCols)`

### retrieve the last row of your destination sheet and write starting with the next row

```
var destLastRow=dest_sheet.getLastRow();
var dest_range = dest_sheet.getRange(destLastRow+1, 1, numRowsDest, numCols);
dest_range.setValues(dest_values);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works. I was unable to skip pasting the header. then I tried changing the var firstRow = 1; to var firstRow = 2; and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Sure, just change `var firstRow = 1;` to `var firstRow = 2;`